# Getting null from a LINQ query even though I have matching result(s)

Tags: c#, linq

Recently I had a task to pick an account from `List<Account>` where the condition was that I have a list of currencies - `List<string> currencies = new List<string> { "USD", "GBP", "EUR" };` and the result should be the first account with currency `USD`, if there's not a such account then one with `currency == GBP` and last any account in `EUR`.

So just to recreate the problem I create a simple class `Account` :

```
class Account
{
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string IBAN { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created two instances:

List accounts = new List();

```
        Account account = new Account();

        account.Amount = 1;
        account.Currency = "USD";
        account.IBAN = "A1";

        accounts.Add(account);

        Account account1 = new Account();

        account1.Amount = 2;
        account1.Currency = "EUR";
        account1.IBAN = "A2";

        accounts.Add(account1);
```

and then I executed this query :

```
var acc = currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
     .Where(a => a.Amount > 1)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

which end up in unexpected (for me) result - an error saying :

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred..
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

I do really need an additional conditions despite the currency order so I'm really confused why I'm getting this result. Also if I change it like that:

```
var acc = currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
     .Where(a => a != null && a.Amount > 1)
     .FirstOrDefault();
```

then it seems that I'm getting the correct behavior but first I really want to know why I have to make this `null` check and second - is this a correct way to perform the task or just a lucky case where I don't get exception?

Comment: @AlexK. Sorry, typo.

Comment: Can you explain what you believe the "or default" part of "first or default" means? Learning why people make mistakes like this helps me design better tools to catch or prevent those mistakes.

Comment: @EricLippert I think that the confusing part for me was that this code was actually working for some time (obviously just a lucky coincidence) so at least for me, I would say that the confusing part was the order of execution of the query. I thought that first this part will be iterated `currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency)` until a match is found. And if no match is found then.. well, I do expect null, but guess I was thinking that somehow `LINQ` is smart enough to stop further execution if no match is found on the currency check.

Comment: @EricLippert Is there a way using Linq which does not require to iterate through the whole collection in case one of the accounts has USD as currency?

Comment: @vc: Use a better data structure which has the objects already sorted by currency (allowing binary search or even direct lookup if "bucket"-ized), or add an index and use that instead.

Comment: @Cameron These would be viable options but what if don't own the collection's definition. It would be nice for instance to have an Aggregate overload allowing to leave the iteration if a match has been found without having to fetch the next items that will be ignored.

Comment: @Leron: You understand now that the "or default" means "if the sequence I'm looking for cannot be found, give me null", yes? The order of execution of the query is in the order it appears on the page.

Comment: @vc74: I'm not sure that I understand the thrust of your question. The list of currencies will be iterated until a match is found; each iteration of the list of currencies iterates until a matching record is found, and then it stops.

Comment: @EricLippert I was thinking of a way to iterate through a collection with the ability to leave early if the result is known before reaching the last element. For instance, if Aggregate had an overload allowing to return the working element if we know it will be the result of the aggregation. In this case, the iteration would be on accounts, not on currencies.

Comment: @vc74: But the query given -- the second one, that works -- does have the property already that it bails out as soon as a match is found. That's why I'm confused; you seem to be asking for something you already have.

Comment: @EricLippert I was more thinking of a solution that uses an iterator on accounts rather than currencies but you're right, that's probably good enough

Comment: @vc74: Ah, I understand the thrust of your question now. You want to iterate over the accounts, keeping track as you go of "the first GBP I saw was..." and so on, so that if you find a USD you bail out immediately, and then if you make it to the end without finding one, you already know whether you have a GBP, etc.  That's a nice idea and yes, some kind of accumulator would work.  I don't know of any off-the-shelf part that does that but it would be pretty straightforward to build one.

Comment: @EricLippert Exactly, that's what I meant, sorry for not being very clear. For instance, it would be nice in the Aggregate block I wrote in my answer to be able to bail out as soon as an account with USD as currency has been reached.

Comment: Is it possible to mess with the mechanism that provides default values for types in C# to implement a NullObject pattern for cases like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`accounts.FirstOrDefault()` returns null for the `"GBP"` currency.

Then you do `a.Amount` with this null value in the `Where()`. I think you want:

```
currencies.Select(currency => accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Currency == currency))
    .Where(a => a != null && a.Amount > 1)   // <-- Added null check
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ahh, I see now, I thought that first `LINQ` will search for an `account` with suitable currency and then proceed to the `Where` clause but it seems that the whole code is executed for each currency. Is that right?

Comment: select name is misleading, it is not selecting items that match, it would be better named 'map' or 'project'. N items go in, N items come out.

Comment: @Leron: That's right, the `Select()` runs the lambda you pass it for every currency. The `Where()` runs on the result of the `Select()` for each of those currencies, and the last `FirstOrDefault()` runs on the result of the `Where()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Cameron wrote, your first FirstOrDefault could return null and introduce a null reference exception in the chain.

A more readable approach could be to use a dictionary:

```
string selectedCurrency = 
  currencies.FirstOrDefault(currency => accountsByCurrency.ContainsKey(currency));
if (selectedCurrency != null)
{
  Account selectedAccount = accountsByCurrency[selectedCurrency];

  // Do something with selected account
}
else
{
  // No account was found
}
```

Or the [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651(v=vs.100).aspx) approach:

```
var currencyRanks = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
  { "USD", 1 },
  { "GBP", 2 },
  { "EUR", 3 }
};

int? workingRank = null;
Account selectedAccount = accounts.Aggregate((working, current) =>
{
  int currentRank = 0;
  if (currencyRanks.TryGetValue(current.Currency, out currentRank) && 
     (currentRank < workingRank))
  {
    workingRank = currentRank;
    return current;
  }

  return working;
};
```

Note that none of these allow to partially iterate the collection and bail out as soon as a 'USD' account has been found.

If your collection is big and you want that behavior too, the old fashion way is still readable:

```
private Account SelectAccountByCurrency(IEnumerable<Account> accounts)
{
  Account result = null;
  int? workingRank = null;

  foreach (Account account in accounts)
  {
    int currentRank = 0;
    if (currencyRanks.TryGetValue(account.Currency, out currentRank)) 
    {        
      if (currentRank == 1)
      {
        return account;
      }
      else if (currentRank < workingRank)
      {
        result = account;
        workingRank = currentRank;
      }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I see `TryeGetValue` used in more and more answers here in `SO` I guess it's more intuitive so maybe I'll give it a try somewhere. But it's the volume of the code - written like that it take much more space, but I guess if this prevent you from making mistakes like mine this is a small price.

Comment: Wow, this could be very handy. I haven't see this approach. do you think that `currencyRanks` could be made `Enum` applying the same logic?

Comment: @Leron You don't have other choice than to use TryGetValue if the dictionary may not contain the keys you're looking for.

Comment: @Leron what would be your enum definition?

Comment: well I guess something pretty standard like `enum Currencies {USD=1, GBP=2, EUR=3};`

Comment: But then would the Currency property be also a Currencies instead of string?

Comment: Hmm, in fact I would say yeah, because it's enumerated, similarly to the index of each list element. But I have to go now. Thank you very much for your support! Much appreciated.